# Finding what window the user is focused on in Xfce

Tags: linux, xfce

when I play osu! on Linux the option to "confine mouse cursor to osu! window" does not work. This means that my mouse cursor will move to my other monitor when I am playing. This is an issue because if I accidentaly click one of my mouse buttons it will tab me out of osu! and I will fail the map.

---

I wanted to make a python script to check if the user is focused on the osu! window, and if they are, it would confine the cursor to that window, but I have no idea how I would check what window the user is focused on.